# How to export a DataFrame to multiple sheets of Excel File

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Assume that I have a dataframe of 8000 rows x 7 columns.

Overview of the data

```
data = pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx')
data.head(10)
```

```
ID          Type    CatID   Val1    val2    Comment      Disposition
20192658     N       52     256     358     Processing    In Progress
20192658     N       53     258     365     repairing     In Progress
20192658     N       53     258     365     Processed     Resloved
20192753     K       98     324     347     Processing    In Progress
20192753     K       87     365     378     Repairing     In Progress
20192753     K       84     357     364     Processed     Resolved
20192854     J       98     324     347     Processing    In Progress
20192854     J       87     365     378     Repairing     In Progress
20192854     J       84     357     364     Processed     Resolved
20192789     M       96     369     345     Processing    In Progress
```

There are around 197 unique ID's in the dataframe.

I'm trying to export the data to Excel with each ID to a separate sheet.

As of now I'm manually filtering the data and appending to each sheet. Is there any simple and better approach in doing soo in python?

**Required Output**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Given your dataframe `data`:

- Iterates through each unique ID and slices the dataframe for those values, and then saves to the file.

```py
import pandas as pd

with pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx') as writer:
    for i, value in enumerate(data.ID.unique(), start=1):
        data[data.ID == value].to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=f'Sheet{i}')
```

- I think you would be better off to name each sheet the ID value instead of `Sheet1`, etc.  e.g. `sheet_name=f'{value}'`

  - This will allow you to discern which sheet each ID is on.
  - [`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

with pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx') as writer:
    for value in data.ID.unique():
        data[data.ID == value].to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=f'{value}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to separate the sections of the file you want in each sheet and run the ExcelWriter method using a with statement

```
output_name = ' '
with pd.ExcelWriter(output_name) as writer:
    data.iloc[0:4].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='my_sheet1')
    data.iloc[4:8].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='my_sheet2')
```

The syntax for slicing the output of the read_excel method may not be correct but the to_excel is a method of DataFrame as long as you get the desired sections of the object data, this should work.